# convert list of strings to html list with mustache

Tags: javascript, mustache

Creating a list with Mustache [works like this](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html):

```
const Mustache = require('mustache');

let template = `
    {{#repo}}
        <b>{{name}}</b>
    {{/repo}}
`

let context={
    repo:[
        {name: "John"},
        {name: "Lisa"},
        {name: "Darth Vader"}
    ]
}
console.log(Mustache.render(template, context))
```

It creates:

```
<b>John</b>
<b>Lisa</b>
<b>Darth Vader</b>
```

My problem is: I would like to work on a list of strings directly.
But this seems incompatible with Mustache. If it is not a list of objects, I don't have a name to use in the template:

```
// my data is just a list of strings
let my_data = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

// to make it compatible with Mustache, it has to become a list of objects
let mustache_version=[{el: "a"}, {el: "b"}, {el: "c"}, {el: "d"}]
```

Is it possible to work on an array of strings with Mustache ?

Please note: I'm not asking how to convert my array into the compatible format. Instead, I would like to feed it as-is to Mustache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [mustache readme](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/):

> When looping over an array of strings, a . can be used to refer to the current item in the list.
>   View:
>
> `{
>    "musketeers": ["Athos", "Aramis", "Porthos", "D'Artagnan"]
>   }`
>
> Template:
>
> `{#musketeers}}
>   * {{.}}
>   {{/musketeers}}`

So in your case, you need just to write:

`{{#repo}}
    <b>{{.}}</b>
 {{/repo}}`

Comment: is this specific to mustache.js ? I can't find it in the mustache docs